# Cmake and Qt5: Using different components of Qt5 in different subdirectories

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, qt5

I want to use the Qt5 library in my subdirectories without adding the all components to each subdirectory. In the parent CMakeLists I use `find_package(Qt5)` to make sure that the library exists and the `Qt5_DIR` variable is set. Example:

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)

find_package(Qt5 COMPONENTS Core REQUIRED)

add_subdirectory(exec1)
add_subdirectory(exec2)
```

In the subdirectory `exec1` I want to use the `Qt5::Xml` component. As far as I have understood CMake, the `Qt5_DIR` variable is passed to the subdirectories. Therefore I do not have to use `find_package` again. Is this assumption correct? Example:

**exec1/CMakeLists.txt**

```
project(exec1)
set(SRC exec1.cpp)
set(HDR exec1.h)

add_executable(exec1 ${SRC} ${HDR})
target_link_libraries(exec1 Qt5::Core Qt5::Xml)
```

In a second subdirectory `exec2` I want to add other components of Qt5. Example:

**exec2/CMakeLists.txt**

```
project(exec2)
set(SRC exec2.cpp)
set(HDR exec2.h)

add_executable(exec2 ${SRC} ${HDR})
target_link_libraries(exec2 Qt5::Core Qt5::Websockets)
```

Does it make any difference if I add all components in the parent CMakeLists.txt instead of choosing for each subproject only some components?
How do I handle this case so that I can exchange Qt5 components in the subdirectories without affecting other subdirectories?
Or is it more convenient to add the `find_package` to each subdirectory instead of using it once in the parent CMakeLists.txt?

Any suggestions and tipps are appreciated.

Comment: Note that it is `Qt5`, not `QT5`. This makes a difference on case-sensitive filesystems (like most Linuxes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use Qt5 components in subdirectories while using `find_package` only once in the root CMakeLists.txt -- which is IMHO the right thing to do -- you will have to list all the wanted components when finding Qt.

So following your example, root CMakeLists.txt should be something like that:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)

find_package(QT5 COMPONENTS Xml Websocket REQUIRED)

add_subdirectory(exec1) # will use Xml
add_subdirectory(exec2) # will use Websocket
```

Note that I removed `Core` since it is implicitly added as a dependency of both `Xml` and `Websocket`. Same goes for the subdirectories:

```
add_executable(exec1 ${SRC} ${HDR})
target_link_libraries(exec1 QT5::Xml)
```

Here `exec1` implicitly links against `Core` component because it is a dependency of `Xml`.